# Listing all users under AWS organization multi accounts

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cli

I need a best practice how to automate listing of all users at once under AWS organization multi accounts using AWS-CLI with any script?

I have tried all possible AWS CLI commands but they are all for manual steps and for individually listing users. Also, I tried to get credentilas report for all accounts, it didnt work for all, I again had to go with manually for individual account to get credential report. We have more then 300 accnts under AWS-organization so I want to automate this task, not manually

Answer (score 0):

I’m not aware of a tool that can accomplish this (but that doesn’t mean that it doesn’t exist).

That being said, I would recommend a different approach to user management across a multi-account organisation:

- Create exactly one account where *all* user accounts are managed and into which users log in.
- Allow usage of other accounts only through assuming roles.
- Disallow creating users in other accounts via SCP.

I understand that you already have an existing organisation with lots of accounts and probably even more users. Setting this up would probably be a very painful activity; especially if users are used for technical purposes (e.g. deployments) as well. But it might be worth the effort as you will have a much easier user management in the future.